# How to enable notifications on lock screen on android

Tags: java, android, firebase

My app work well, and notifications with FCM too. But, notifications only show in status bar, and not on lock screen and no led light is blinking.

I can do this working, but I have to enable lock screen notification, led, ... in my device application parameters.

How can my app have theses parameters enabled by default ? I did not found any permission to do that :(

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

this may depend on [Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) configuration. On 8.0+ channel/notification has importance set to `IMPORTANCE_MIN`, below 8.0 has priority set to `PRIORITY_MIN`. Inspect your configuration and increase importance/priority